# Is it possible to convert interface type to a value?

Tags: java, interface, casting, anonymous-types

I have an interface:

```
public interface TestFace {
    public String outThis();
}
```

A class with a method whose parameter is of the interface type,:

```
class MyClass {
    public void outMeth(TestFace inMeth){
        System.out.print(inMeth); //the method attempts to print the interface type
   }
}
```

If I call the object's method like so:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
a.outMeth(new TestFace() {
            public String outThis() {
                String val = "something";
                return val;
            }
        });
```

the printed value is a reference to the instance. Could someone explain why this happens/how to do this properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "how do do this properly"? How to do *what* properly?

Comment: Also, why are you writing `int val = "something"`?  `"something"` is a `String`, not an `int`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman woops, fixed, thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet Output the string value properly, rather than it's reference. Sorry, seemed obvious...

Comment: @supremus_01 why should the `String` result of some random method that could mean anything be relevant to that object's representation when you print it out?  What if the `String` method is `fireNukesAndPrintNumberOfRemainingHumans`?

Comment: What string value? The string value resulting from the call to the `outThis()` method? Because you're not actually *calling* the method at the moment... Perhaps you meant `System.out.print(inMeth.outThis());`? (It doesn't help that the code you've given won't compile, because `outie` and `outThis` are different names...)

Comment: (As in my answer below, if you want a method to be relevant to an object's `String` representation, you need to override its `toString()` method and say so.)

Comment: i apologize, poor editing!

Comment: Oh, and I've just noticed that the method is meant to return an `int`, not a string. So again, the code you've got won't compile. Please put together a [mcve] - it'll make it a lot easier to help you, although I suspect I *may* have already given you the answer. (The question still isn't clear...)

Comment: Sorry, this was a mess. again, apologies for the poor editing.

Comment: I still don't see why you expected the method to be called automatically, or why you don't just call it in your outMeth method.

Comment: @JonSkeet the method is defined in the class and later called under the instance name `a`. This was nothing more than conceptual experimentation with the use of anonymous types. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, you didn't provide any code which called the method. You implemented the method, but never called it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm a little confused... Do you mean the contracted method `outThis`? it has a return statement which is executed, why would I/how would I even call it in this form?

Comment: @supremus_01: Nope, in the code you provided in the question, the method is never executed. I showed you how you'd execute it ages ago: `System.out.print(inMeth.out this());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of doing `System.out.println` on an `Object` will always be the result of invoking the object's `toString()` method.  If you inherit that from `Object` (by not writing an explicit `toString()`), you get the default `Object` implementation, which is specified:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

The "name" of an anonymous class generally reflects the class in which the anonymous class was defined, often with `$1` or the like added to the end.

If you want a more useful `toString()`, override it and write one yourself:

```
    new TestFace() {
        public String outie() {
            String val = "something";
            return val;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return outie();
        }
    }
```

Comment: and thanks for being able to see past the poor editing.

Comment: I think it would be worth mentioning the alternative of changing the body of `outMeth` to `System.out.print(inMeth.outThis());` - it's pretty odd to make a method accept a parameter of a given interface, but not actually *use* that information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print `val`, just override the `toString()` method.

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
a.outMeth(new TestFace() {
    public int outie() {
        int val = "something";
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return outie();
    }
});
```